# How can I delete the 0-8th and then the second from the top line in a file [Python]

Tags: file, python-3.x, edit

Here is a [link](http://or.water.usgs.gov/non-usgs/bes/cottrell_school.rain) to a text file I am trying to format.

I am attempting to format the file so it ends up looking like this.

```
   Date     Total    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
20-MAY-2016     0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19-MAY-2016    35    0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0   1   0   0   7   6   2   4   2   2   3   5   0   0   0   0   0

...
```

So my thought is to remove the top (0-8) lines first, then remove the second from the top `---------` line 
If

So far I have this code

```
lines = open('data.csv').readlines()
open('data.csv', 'w').writelines(lines[9:])
```

The above code will delete the 0-8th lines.

But I am not sure what how to proceed from here. 
I have tried quite a few things but I will save you from reading my errors.

Also I realize I have to close the file once I am done writing to it, I just omitted that, as I am not done writing to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC here is a solution using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) and most probably you wanted to analyse the data after this and pandas suits it well:

```
import pandas as pd
#header=7 make 7th row as header
#skiprows=[10] skip the 10 row, if you need you can add a list of rows here
df= pd.read_csv('http://or.water.usgs.gov/non-usgs/bes/cottrell_school.rain',header=7, skiprows=[10])
#After this if you wnated to save it in other formats
#Use df.to_csv('formatted.csv') or df.to_excel('formatted.xlsx')
```

And refer to this [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) for list of IO options.

Comment: That is great I was actually going to use pandas for another reason!